# How to do the multiplicity for one or many coding in java

Tags: java

I need to know how to code the one to many multiplicities in java.  I know that If it's one too many,  that class must always have an object of another class to instantiate. So basically I have to pass an object of another class as an argument in the constructor. I'm just confused about how to implement this. If someone can provide me with an example I would be glad.

Comment: Please elaborate more on one to many multiplicity

Comment: Share some example. It's not clear what problem you are trying to solve

Comment: for example, think about a Vehicle ticketing system. In that, if one ticket has one or more payment allocations, that can be a one to many relationship among the two entities.

Comment: by example everyone here means a minimal snippet of code that shows what you have tried so far. something minimal would be some inputs to a function, a loop that runs the function, and then the expected output. doing that might even help you answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have a class Foo that may contain multiple Bars, but a Bar is assigned to one and only one Foo.

```
class Foo {
     public ArrayList<Bar> myBars;
     void addBar(Bar bar) {
         myBars.add(bar);
     }
}

class Bar {
     public Foo myFoo;

     public Bar(Foo foo) {
         myFoo = foo;
         foo.addBar(this);
     }
}
```

Note that Bar could have a default constructor and you can use a setter instead.

Is this what you mean?

Note that in this example, I'm keeping track of both directions. That is, there's a to-one relationship from Bar to Foo (Bar has one Foo), but there's a to-many relationship of Foo to Bar (a Foo can have many Bars).